# Need a simple Flash preloader for Actionscript 2 using ProgressBar component

Tags: actionscript-2, flash-cs6, preloader

I've been looking for an ActionScript 2.0 preloader using the ProgressBar component, and I can't find an example of this.  Can anyone direct me to a nice tutorial for this? I just want to add a simple preloader to the beginning of my movie.  It doesn't load any external movies. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked down the coded I needed to use with the ProgressBar component:

```
myProgressBarListener = new Object();
myProgressBarListener = function (eventObject) {
myProgressBar._visible = false;
gotoAndPlay(2); 
};

myProgressBar.addEventListener("complete", myProgressBarListener);
myProgressBar.mode = "polled";
myProgressBar.source = "_root";
myProgressBar.conversion = "1";
myProgressBar.label = "LOADING %3%%";
myProgressBar.direction = "right";
myProgressBar.labelPlacement = "bottom";
stop();
```

This is good for AS 2.0 and I'm using CS6. I'm not sure how this works for other versions of Flash.